# How to save duplicate records in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

I'm creating an application where it simulates a football album for each user, the logic is that each user can open packages and receive players that in the future can be associated with teams that the user himself created. To save all the players that a user can receive I created a Player model (
many-to-many relationship with users and teams):

```
class Player(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False)
  birthdate = db.Column(db.Date())
  weight = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=5, scale=2), nullable=False)
  height = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
  users = db.relationship(User, secondary = 'user_player', overlaps='players')
  teams = db.relationship('Team', secondary = 'player_team', overlaps='players')
```

As much as a player (card) can be assigned to several users and several teams, it is not possible for a user to receive the same player in duplicate, where he could associate it with another team that he himself created. How can I make a user receive the same player more than once without having to create another record in the database?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you need an intermediate table. You have a db.Model "Player" with basic information as on a player card. Then a "User" and a "Team" model. The team has a relation to the user, now you create a "UserCollection" db.Model, which contains references such as PlayerId, UserId and TeamId if set.

Comment: The idea might work, but every time I need to see a user's cards I'll need to query the Collection, get the ids and then query the ids to see which players are. This would be more complicated for the backend.

Comment: That's right, I'm afraid it doesn't get any easier as this is standard practice for a many-to-many SQL relationship. [info-link](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab)

Comment: I understood your logic, I will try to follow this path to finish the project. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score -1):

You should use "ManytoManyField" like this;

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

it gives to you add more then one relation without new line or table;

```
a1 = Article(headline='Django lets you build web apps easily')
p1 = Publication(title='The Python Journal')
p2 = Publication(title='Science News')
p3 = Publication(title='Science Weekly')
p1.save()
p2.save()
p3.save()
a1.save()
```

and you can start the add new relations;

```
a1.publications.add(p1, p2)
a1.publications.add(p3)
```

for more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/